# AVPlayer, changing streams cause overlays

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, overlay, avplayer

lastly I'm developing a streaming app using AVPlayer. I have some channels and change them using swipe gesture. When I swipe channels to fast it causes streams' overlaying, so when I'm at a specified stream, the previous stream layer might be overlayed in the current stream.

The code to setup player is :

```
if let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: stream){
                self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
                self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)
                self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
                self.playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
                self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.playerLayer, below: self.tvView.layer)
                self.player.play()


                self.addObservers()
            }
```

and when I get the next channel, I try to destroy the previous one using this code:

```
if(self.player != nil){
            self.player.pause()
            self.player = nil
        }
        if(self.playerLayer != nil){
            for layer in self.view.layer.sublayers!{
                if(layer == self.playerLayer){
                    layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                }
            }
        }
        self.removeObservers()
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem because it is really stressing me. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by overlay? Like it is playing both previous stream and the stream you just started to play?

Comment: @u.gen yes exactly, swiping normally it goes everything fine but when I swipe them so fast they are put over each other and i got two streams playing in the same time.

Comment: How long do they play together, only couple of seconds or indefinitely?

Comment: If I don't take any action it plays indefinitely, then, when I try to change the channel I get an error related with the observers I added like this "Cannot remove an observer  for the key path "playbackBufferEmpty" from <AVPlayerItem> because it is not registered as an observer." I call the method of adding observers after I setup player and remove them when I change the channel after checking if observers were added. @u.gen

Comment: First of all add and remove observes from the player not from playerItem, because you need a player to play the player item anyway. I think I need to see more code to help you because sounds like either you are creating multiple players or player items.

Comment: 'func removeObservers(){
        
        if(obsAdded == "yes"){
            self.player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty")
            self.player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp")
            self.player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull")
            obsAdded = "no"
            self.endTime = Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
        } else {
            print("there is nothing to remove")
            obsAdded = "no"
        }
    }' this is where i remove observers

Comment: func addObservers(){
        if(obsAdded == "no"){
            self.player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
            self.player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
            self.player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(), context: nil)
            obsAdded = "yes"
            
        } else {
            obsAdded = "no"
        }
    }
this is where i add them @u.gen